# How to make a macro ignore tables?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code that deletes the paragraph following any entirely bold paragraphs (i.e. deletes blank lines following subheadings), but this has caused an issue with the part of my macro that converts text to tables, in that it deletes the content following a table header when the table has bold headers. Is there a way I can get this code to ignore tables?

```
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim searchRange As Range

Set searchRange = Selection.Range
searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

For Each para In searchRange.Paragraphs
    If para.Range.Font.Bold = True Then para.Next.Range.Delete
Next para
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `Information` property of the Range.

Try something like:

```
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim searchRange As Range

Set searchRange = Selection.Range
searchRange.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End

For Each para In searchRange.Paragraphs
    If para.Range.Font.Bold = True And Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then para.Range.Next.Delete
Next para
```